# pip says it is a package, by python says it is not

Tags: python

I am using Windows and have a directory like this:

```
troopcalc/
    setup.py
    troopcalc/
        __init__.py
        troopcalc.py
        troopcfg.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_troopcalc.py
            test_troopcfg.py
```

I used pip to install the package... and pip list shows the package installed and pointing to the top of the dir structure.

---

`troopcfg.py`:

```
class TroopCfg(object):
...
```

---

`troopcalc.py`:

```
from troopcalc.troopcfg import TroopCfg
```

---

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='troopcalc',
    version='0.1',
    description='Calculates troop distribution',
    url='...',
    author='Randell ...',
    author_email='...',
    packages=['troopcalc', 'troopcalc.tests', 'troopcalc.data'],
    package_dir={'troopcalc': 'troopcalc', 'troopcalc.tests': 'troopcalc/tests', 'troopcalc.data': 'troopcalc/data'},
    package_data={'troopcalc.data': ['*.json']},
    )
```

---

If I run `python .\troopcalc.py` I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\troopcalc.py", line 2, in <module>
    from troopcalc.troopcfg import TroopCfg
  File "...\python\troopcalc\troopcalc\troopcalc.py", line 2, in <module>
    from troopcalc.troopcfg import TroopCfg
ImportError: No module named 'troopcalc.troopcfg'; 'troopcalc' is not a package
```

pip says it is a package, but python says it is not. The goal is not to use absolute paths of course. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post all of the import lines in all of the Python files? And can you also fix the formatting for the directory structure since it's difficult to understand.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I didn't notice the directory structure got smashed.  The __init__.py's are all blank.

Comment: careful to break it, i did fix it for you already

Comment: I think I got it all cleaned up and with all the requested info.

Comment: A number of possible issues. First up, pip can sometimes be wrong - eg it sometimes shows installations that failed (most common when a compiler or dependencies isn't available). Next up, just because the code doesn't work, doesn't necessarily mean the package isn't installed. Have you got the correct `PYTHONPATH`? Are you certain that you're not using a name that's masking the library? Are your `import` statements referring to the appropriate object (class, module, etc)?

Comment: I printed out sys.path, and it has both the top level troopcalc and troopcalc/troopcalc on the path. and troopcalc/troopcalc is actually first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I run `python .\troopcalc.py` I get the following:

Well, yes. Python thinks that `troopcalc` is `troopcalc.py`, since that's in the directories in `sys.path`.

```
python -m troopcalc.troopcalc
```

Comment: In order to run `.\troopcalc.py` he would have to already be inside the troopcalc directory, so this won't work.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  yeah, troopcalc.py is there, but when I use      `import troopcalc.troopcfg`  shouldn't it look for a package not a module?

Comment: It will only look in directories in `sys.path`. If you're running `troopcalc.py` then the `troopcalc` package won't be found in any of the directories in `sys.path`.

Comment: sys.path shows that .../troopcalc is on the path always.  The current directory of the py file I run is also on the path, just first.  So it sounds like it is finding the module first because it is first on the path?

Comment: Correct. The directory containing the executed script is always first.

Comment: sounds like the bottom line is that one shouldn't have a module of the same name as the package.  I will try renaming it and see if things start working.

Comment: yep, that did it.  eveything works now that the moduel name is different.  Thanks everyone for your help.